# map method displaying project name multiple times?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map an array, and display the names of each project in the array, but for some reason, the names keep displaying in proportion with the number of items in the array. So if the array has three items, the item will display three times instead of the desired one.

I've added the project to a sandBox to explain the problem more clearly, the code is really bad because this is my first Project, but the issue is happing in the Projects.js files.

When you go on the sandbox, click the grey button to add a project, a small window will pop out, and you can click the add button to add the project, if you do this exact same process again, another project will be added, but with double the names and that's the issue here, keep adding projects, and the names on each project will multiply. I don't know how to fix it, I saw another sandBox that implemented the same map function I have in Project.js I did and all works perfectly for them.

sandBox => https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-firefly-uprlpf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: seems like forgot to add components folder in the codesandbox. Please ensure issue is reproducible in the given codesandbox

Comment: The updates didn't show up it seems, I'll fix it later.